# How to sandwich a content div between two fixed-width columns

Tags: css, html

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexy0202/DbQUN/). I've got divs on either side, with fixed widths of 50px, and `display:inline-block`.

I want the div on the inside to expand to fill the gap between these two divs, but the problem is if I put lots of text inside this div it pushes itself onto the next line, and the layout breaks down.

Also, I want it so the middle div will fill the space even if there is a small amount of text in it (less than the page width).

How can I ensure the left and right divs are always on the left and right, and that the content div always fills the space in between them?

I tried using CSS3's `calc`, but it appears that it [isn't very well supported](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of situation that was handled in the past by using tables for layout.  This will be fixed in the future by the new Flexbox implementation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox

In the meantime, you can emulate the table effect by using display: table-cell, this will cause each div to stretch the way you would expect a table to.  If you want more control over the total width you can wrap it in a div that has a display: table-row and a set width.

```
.col {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#EEE;
    width:50px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.middle {
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:#333;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using javascript, this will work:

```
​$(function(){
    $('div.middle').width( $('div.container').width() - $('div.right.col').width() - $('div.left.col').width() - 10 );

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('div.middle').width( $('div.container').width() - $('div.right.col').width() - $('div.left.col').width() - 10 );
    });

});
```

Working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vh8Zu/